# acions on google smart home app not calling fullfilment

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am trying to make an actions on google smart home app. I have implemented my oAuth2.0 server which seems to work fine. It generates an authorization token and sends it to Google with the `state` parameter provided by Google. However, when I try to do the account linking in my google home app, it fails with the default `couldn't update the setting` error. When I check my Firebase console, it says my smartHome function - the smart home fulfillment I provided in the actions on Google console - was never called, even though the other functions completed successfully.

What is the cause/solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide the actual error that you get?

Comment: Can you also provide some code? Where you ask for a sign-in, where you reveice the SIGN_IN_SUCCESSFUL event...

Comment: @RémiC. Isn't that only if i am using something like dialogflow. the sign in is completely on my server.

Comment: @NickFelker the code to create and exchange tokens runs without error. however in the google home app in the account linking page, it says : `couldn't update the setting. try checking your connection`

Comment: Can you post a short code snippet of your fulfillment?

Comment: @NickFelker even though the fullfilment is never called, do you want a snippet of that code?

Comment: Yeah, it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

The Smart Home fulfillment is never called for your action because apparently your OAuth flow is not correctly set up. Please visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/implement-oauth) and make sure that everything is set up according to the authorization code flow.

Furthermore, `Test Suite` can also be used to validate the account linking implementation: https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/smart-home-test-suite#account_linking_validation_test